# Пожалуйста, помогите с пунктуацией в стихотворении!

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, поэзия

Тебе нравятся мои стихи?
Простила бы за это мне грехи?
Я верю в тебя и верю, что да.
Ты ведь в моем мире навсегда!
Я хочу сейчас увидеть тебя снова
Услышать хотя бы одно слово
Твой необычный и мой любимый голос,
Но остался здесь на кофте лишь твой волос.
Я по тебе скучаю, стало тише.
И вот друг другу мы не пишем.
Хотя я вспоминаю лишь тебя одну
Когда сквозь голубую тюль видно луну.
И даже если ты сейчас соврешь
Как бы не пыталась-нить не оборвешь!
И когда то я спрошу уже глухим:
Тебе нравились мои стихи?

Comment: «Пожалуйста, помогите с пунктуацией?» — просьба или вопрос?

Comment: Это определенно просьба)

Comment: Текст сложно править из-за стилистических ошибок, есть и орфографические.

Answer (score 2):

Несомненно, знаки препинания можно расставить по-разному. Есть обязательные, есть авторские. Мой вариант (изменения — в скобках):

Тебе нравятся мои стихи?
Простила бы за это мне грехи?
Я верю в тебя и верю, что да[, —]
Ты ведь в моем мире навсегда!
Я хочу сейчас увидеть тебя снова[,]
Услышать хотя бы одно слово [—]
Твой необычный и [такой] любимый голос[!]
Но остался здесь на кофте лишь твой волос[...]
Я по тебе скучаю[!] Стало тише[,]
И вот друг другу мы не пишем[,]
Хотя я вспоминаю лишь тебя одну[,]
Когда сквозь [тюль в окне] видно луну.
И даже если ты сейчас соврешь[,]
Как бы не пыталась [—] нить не оборвешь!
И когда[-]то я спрошу[,] уже глухим:
Тебе нравились мои стихи?

Примечание 1. Фразу "Твой необычный и мой любимый голос" я не мог не исправить.
Примечание 2. Чтобы снять проблемы с прилагательным при слове *тюль*, я заменил "голубую тюль" на "тюль в окне".

Comment: "Голуб**ая** тюль" даже в стихотворных интересах вряд ли допустима :)

Comment: Да, распростаненная ошибка, и я ее пропустил. Даже Википедия указывает, что в разговорном языке тюль часто ошибочно употребляют в женском роде.

Comment: @grizzly Спаcибо! Я исправил.

Comment: @grizzly У многих классиков тюль была женского рода. Навскидку:  _Прибранная, спокойная, выпрямленная, вот и спину ее наконец-то «отпустило», в черном вязаном платочке, белой тюлью прикрытая._ (В. Астафьев. Последний поклон)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, интересно. Но странно :)

Comment: Не странно уже: 50 на 50, хорошо, что не бесполый.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе ведь по нраву мои все стихи?
Я верю в тебя и верю, что да:
За них ты отпустишь мне все-все грехи
И будешь ты в мире моём навсегда!
Хочу сейчас тебя увидеть  снова,
Твой необычный и любимый голос
Услышать - ну хотя бы слово;
Но здесь, на кофте - только твой волос.
Я по тебе скучаю, стало тише,
Тебя я вспоминаю лишь одну,
Хотя друг другу больше мы не пишем.
Вернуть бы ту за тюлем голубым луну!
И даже если ты сейчас соврёшь,
Когда спрошу я уже глухим:
"Тебе ведь нравились мои стихи?",
Как ни пытайся - нить не оборвёшь!